# Using handles and System watcher in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a really hard time to understand handles and really I am not getting anywhere even tho I am trying to do this for days .My problem is like this,I want my code to be running when a window is opened,for example "Untitled - Notepad" ,so when I open the notepad my code should be running.I have a windows Form app and saw there is an event called ManagementEventWatcher that seems to not be working.

I got to something like this until now.

```
      [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);  
 private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
                if (notepads.Length == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No test running","Why u do dis?");
                } 
                else if (notepads[0] != null)
                {
                    IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                    string text = "";
                    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                    {
                        text += item.ToString() ;
                        SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, text);

                    }               
                }        
}
```

Which sends my listbox1.Items to an opened notepad when I press the send button,but this is not what I want,I want my app to detect the Opened `Untitled - Notepad` window and do that automatically .It would help me if someone would show me exactly how this is done and explain it also to me with documentations.

#### Edit

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

From Matthew Watson answer I got answered to most of my question with even more improvisation that I did not ask for but I will take them dearly :) .But still one question remains.How can I create an event using `ManagementEventWatcher` so it will automatically detect when a `Untitled - Notepad` is opened instead of clicking a button.

Code after update:

```
[DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
 var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad");

            if (notepad != null)
            {
                if (IsIconic(notepad.MainWindowHandle))
                    ShowWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 9);

                SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);
                string text = "";

                    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                    {
                       text += item.ToString();

                    }

                Clipboard.SetText(text);
                SendKeys.Send("^V");

            }
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#### Edit 2

[image]

Comment: You are looking for processes named Notepad, so of course you will find all of them. You then have to filter that list by finding the main window of each process (if any) and its title.

Comment: Lets say I will never have more than one opened.lets start from there.

Comment: You say you want a window with the title "Untitled - Notepad", but you don't test for that in your program.

Comment: because in my program I test by the process,and I would like to test by the window actual name which doesn't work like this.Because as I said I really do not understand how this all works,I really tried to understand but it's just not working.That is why I am asking for help here

Comment: If your question is "given the handle of a window, how do I get its title?", than ask that question, or type it in Google. That yields this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx

Comment: and how do you tie this with an system watcher event? so I can run my code when the `Untitled - Notepad` is opened.

Comment: First I wrote file system watcher because I am very,very ...tired.In the comments you saw I did not write `files` system watcher just system watcher because that is what I meant.I don't know why people urge to be mean but I will take your comment as it is.I don't think you need to be mean to anyone without knowing their situation ,I came here asking for help,I posted some mistakes(we all do them,I guess if you got what I wanted to say you could answer me if u knew what i wanted to ask no need to be like that) ,you could ask me for more info on what I meant ... not by testing my knowledge.

Comment: I'm trying to help. I don't know what you think, I only read what you say. Edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a different approach for this:

1. Find a Notepad window with the title "Untitled - Notepad"
2. If it is minimised, unminimise it.
3. Bring it to the foreground.
4. Populate the system clipboard with the text you want to paste into Notepad.
5. Use `SendKeys()` to send Ctrl+V to Notepad, to paste the clipboard contents.

Something like this:

```
[DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad");

    if (notepad != null)
    {
        if (IsIconic(notepad.MainWindowHandle))
            ShowWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 9);

        SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);

        Clipboard.SetText("Here's some text to paste into the Notepad window");
        SendKeys.Send("^V");
    }
}
```

---

In order to determine when a process has been started, you can use [`class ManagementEventWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'Notepad.exe'");
var mew = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
mew.EventArrived += (sender, args) => { notepadStarted(); };
mew.Start();
```

**However, note that watching for processes to start requires elevated permissions.** In other words, if you do this then your application will need to run as an administrator.

Here's a complete example `Form` implementation that will paste some text into Notepad when it is opened:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'Notepad.exe'");
            var mew = new ManagementEventWatcher(query) {Query = query};
            mew.EventArrived += (sender, args) => { notepadStarted(); };
            mew.Start();
        }

        void notepadStarted()
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(pasteIntoNotepad));
        }

        [DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        void pasteIntoNotepad()
        {
            var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad");

            if (notepad != null)
            {
                notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

                if (IsIconic(notepad.MainWindowHandle))
                    ShowWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 9);

                SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);

                Clipboard.SetText("Here's some text to paste\r\ninto the Notepad window");
                SendKeys.Send("^V");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to run this as an administrator, otherwise it will throw an access denied exception.

Also note that this does NOT handle multiple instances of Notepad all with the same title "Untitled - Notepad"!

Comment: One thing still not answered , I don't want to send my information with the send button ,that is how I have done it because I don't know how to use the system watcher.I want my app to automatically detect that I opened a notepad and execute the code .

Comment: @JohnPietrar You could use ManagementEventWatcher for that - I'll see if I can find some sample code.

Comment: Do I need some more directives or assembly references? Because it trows me this error:`The type or namespace name 'WqlEventQuery' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
`

Comment: @JohnPietrar Yes, you need to add a reference to `System.Management`

Comment: Strange,but I seem to not have that reference

Comment: @JohnPietrar You should have - exactly what version of .Net is your project using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0.25123.00 update 2 and. Net framework v. 4.6.01055

Comment: @JohnPietrar It should definitely be there if you go to Solution Explorer | References | Add Reference | Assemblies | Framework

Comment: ah wait! In framework,I was looking in COM,sorry ,my bad

Comment: @JohnPietrar Did you read the text in my answer that I wrote in bold because it was so important? ;)

Comment: Sorry Matthew,I am really tired and read be logged in as administrator not run as administrator,thank you a lot for your patience with me,you are a truly amazing human being :) It works perfect.Thanks a lot again :)